# "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter "a" of "Form1.LOCa(double, double, double...)

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            abox.Text = "0";
            bbox.Text = "0";
            cbox.Text = "0";
            c.Text = "0";

        }

        private void calc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {// IF COS IS CHECKED
            if (p.Checked)

            {
                //Declaring Variables
                double a = Double.Parse(abox.Text);

                double b = Double.Parse(bbox.Text);

                double can = Double.Parse(cbox.Text);
                //Run the methods for answers
                double pAns = cos(a, b, can);
                //Output answers
                c.Text = string.Format("{0}", pAns);


            }
            // IF Law Of Cosines IS CHECKED
            if (sin.Checked)
            { //Declaring Variables
            double a = Double.Parse(abox.Text);

            double b = Double.Parse(bbox.Text);

            double can = Double.Parse(cbox.Text);

            //Run the methods for answers
            double sumA = LOCa(a, b, can);
                double sumB = LOCb(a, b, can);
                double answer = cos(a, b, can);
                //Output answers
                c.Text = string.Format("{0}", answer);
                AngA.Text = string.Format("{0}", sumA);
                AngB.Text = string.Format("{0}", sumB);
            }
        }//Method for plain Cosine
        static double cos(double a, double b, double can)
        { //COS math
           double sum = (a * a) + (b * b) - (2 * a * b * Math.Cos(can));
            //Square root it
            double answer = Math.Sqrt(sum);
            return answer;

        }//Law of cosine angle A
        static double LOCa(double a, double b, double can)
        {  //Sum = c
           double sum = (a * a) + (b * b);
            //Square root C
           double answer = Math.Sqrt(sum);
            //Law of cosines math
            double sumA = ((b * b) + (sum * sum) + (-1 * (a * a))) / (2 * b * sum);
            //Return the answer
            return sumA;


        }
        //Law of cosine angle B
        static double LOCb(double a, double b, double can)
        {
            double sum = (a * a) + (b * b);
            double answer = Math.Sqrt(sum);
            double sumB = ((a * a) - (b * b) + (sum * sum)) / (2 * b * sum);
            return sumB;


        }


    }
}
```

This will be  a Program that calculates the length of one side of a triangle, given the lengths of the other two sides and the value of the included angle. The triangle need not be a right triangle. The other two methods are additional methods to calculate the values of the other two angles using the Law of Cosines. All of my methods have the same error indicating "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter "a" of "method(double, double, double...) and I have looked at questions and responses to this question but none of them are basic enough for me (I am in my first class of programming at high school). Any solutions?

Comment: What do you  mean by passing? How should I pass them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have to write like

```
Double.Parse("ac.Text");
```

but

```
Double.Parse(ac.Text);
```

because you have to pass the content of such controls, while you are passing the string "ac.Text" instead

and to method cos you didn't pass any parameter, while you have to pass

```
cos(a,b, etc...
```

Comment: This is in a GUI and when I take the quotations away it gives me the error " Double does not contain a definition for "text""

Comment: Because you have two objects called `a`. One is the text box, the other is the `double` used to hold the value. Consider renaming your variables and controls.

Answer (score 0):

Your methods `LOCa` and `LOCb` have parameters:

```
static double LOCa(double a, double b, double sumA, double answer, double ac, double sumB, double sum)
{
}

static double LOCb(double a, double b, double sumA, double answer, double ac, double sumB, double sum)
{
}
```

but you are calling them without:

```
        double sumA = LOCa();
        double sumB = LOCb();
```

You need to provide the arguments so the compiler can find them in your code. At the moment there are no suitable methods, which is why you are getting the error.

The more I look at the code the more there is wrong. Most of the parameters should be variables declared inside the methods:

```
static double LOCa(double a, double b)
{
    //Sum = c
    double sum = (a * a) + (b * b);
    //Square root C
    double answer = Math.Sqrt(sum);
    //Law of cosines math
    double sumA = ((b * b) + (sum * sum) + (-1 * (a * a))) / (2 * b * sum);
    //Return the answer
    return sumA;
}
```

and called like this:

```
double sumA = LOCa(a, b);
```

with the same for LOCb.

Comment: Do I need to add every parameter inside LOCa(a, b); ?   Ex. LOCa(a, b, sum, answer, ac)?  Also when you say "The more I look at the code the more there is wrong." what else is there? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @GraysonFelt - No. Parameters are there to hold the values passed **to** the method (not the whole picture, but close enough for now). If it needs to store intermediate steps in the calculation they should be declared inside the method.